# Unable to load angular component in mapbox-gl popup

Tags: angular, mapbox, mapbox-gl

Unable to render angular component in popup

```
var popUp=new mapboxgl.Popup().setHTML("<vas-map-hover [marker]='marker'></vas-map-hover>");
var markerObj = new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
          .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
          .setPopup(popUp)
          .addTo(self.map);
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Do you get any errors? And at what point in the lifecycle are you running this code?

Comment: It's not rendering the actual template for vas-map-hover component.

Comment: it's probably because angular sanitizer sanitizes your html to be "safe" to prevent XSS attacks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mapbox GL Popup set content with custom tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48229709/mapbox-gl-popup-set-content-with-custom-tag)

Comment: any answer i use latest version  ?