# NullInjectorError: No provider for ViewContainerRef! in Angular Service

Tags: angular, angular14

I recently updated my code from Angular 13 to version 14.2.x and saw that `ComponentFactoryResolver` is deprecated. Decided to update the few instances of `ComponentFactoryResolver` in my library, but started running into the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(ModalDemoModule)[ModalService -> DomService -> ViewContainerRef -> ViewContainerRef -> ViewContainerRef -> ViewContainerRef -> ViewContainerRef]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for ViewContainerRef!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(ModalDemoModule)[ModalService -> DomService -> ViewContainerRef -> ViewContainerRef -> ViewContainerRef -> ViewContainerRef -> ViewContainerRef]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for ViewContainerRef!
```

Basically, I have a `dom.service.ts` that creates a consistent way to append new components to the DOM. Then I have a `modal.service.ts` and `tooltip.service.ts` that handles modals and tooltips, which uses `dom.service.ts`.

```
@Injectable()
export class DomService {
  private renderer: Renderer2;

  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document,
    private appRef: ApplicationRef,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private injector: Injector,
    private rendererFactory: RendererFactory2,
  ) {
    this.renderer = this.rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
  }
```

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ModalService {
  constructor(
    private domService: DomService,
  ) {}
```

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class TooltipService {
  constructor(
    private domService: DomService,
  ) {}
```

This was working when I utilized the `ComponentFactoryResolver`. I have seen other solutions, but I would like to keep the code as similar to what it currently is, if possible.

- [How can I inject ViewContainerRef into a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636840/how-can-i-inject-viewcontainerref-into-a-service)
- https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71364435/1

Any suggestions? Is this just a stupid pattern that I should abandon? Thanks for any help!

I have tried a portion of the solution outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636840/how-can-i-inject-viewcontainerref-into-a-service) by injecting the `ViewContainerRef` into `modal.service.ts` and then providing it to `dom.service.ts`. I I also tried to make `dom.service.ts` a singleton and inject it into my demo application's top-level module, but no luck. Not really sure where else to go without potentially doing a major refactor, which I would like to avoid if possible since things were working fine before.

Comment: Any solution for this issue? I am struggling with the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I have not found a solution yet (though I have not tried again in about a month). I ended up replacing all of the instances of `ComponentFactoryResolver` where I could, and left the problem areas alone for now.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution that I think can work well for your use case, as I have a very similar situation (I have a `dom.service` which I use as the service to append DOM elements from other services, such as a notification and a modal service).

Digging around StackOverflow I found this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/45263, in which AndrewKushnir comments that they are working in a replacement for this behavior, and looking at the completed PR (https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/46685) I saw that a new function was available from `@angular/core`: `createComponent`.

Now, my `dom.service` looks something like this (ommiting some types because they are very application specific):

```typescript
import { ComponentType } from '@angular/cdk/portal';
import {
  ApplicationRef,
  EnvironmentInjector,
  Injectable,
  createComponent
} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DomService {
  constructor(private appRef: ApplicationRef, private environmentInjector: EnvironmentInjector) {}

  public appendComponentTo(childComponentType: ComponentType<any>, target?: Element) {
    const childComponentRef = createComponent(childComponentType, {
      environmentInjector: this.environmentInjector
    });

    this.appRef.attachView(childComponentRef.hostView);

    // Some more work to append DOM element to the body, possibly as a child node to the argument target
    // ...

    return childComponentRef;
  }
```

This way you can work around the need to use a ViewContainerRef.